# Command in expect for grep keyword

Tags: awk, ssh, tcl, expect, send

Expect script query:

In one of my expect script I have to pick keyword from output of send command and store in a file, could some one help me.

```
send "me\n"
output : 
EM/X Nmis Ssh Session/2; Userid = 
Impact = ; Scope = ; CustomerId = 0
```

Here I want to pick keyword : `Nmis Ssh Session/2`
and my target is to create new command in expect script is :

```
send "set Nmis Ssh Session/2 \n"
```

so this value : `Nmis Ssh Session/2` should store in a variable. Could some one help me.

Comment: -3 and not a single comment. That's nice, community.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure exactly what information is produced by which side, but *maybe* something like this will do:

```
expect -re {EM/X ([^;]+);}
set theVariable $expect_out(1,string)
```

The key is that we use the `-re` option to pass a *regular expression* to the `expect` command. That makes the text that matches what is in the parentheses (a sequence of non-semicolon characters) be stored in the variable `expect_out(1,string)` (there are many other things stored in the `expect_out` array; see [the documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)). Copying it from there to a named variable for the purpose of storage and further manipulation is trivial.

I do not know if the RE is the right one; there's something of an art in choosing the right one, and it takes quite a lot of knowledge about what the *possible* output of the other side could be.